# XPATH Get Header TH for a specific Column TD

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I currently have a table that has the follow layout

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Header One</th>
   <th>Header Two</th>
   <th class="headerBorder">H</th>
   <th>Header Three</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>A</td>
   <td>B</td>
   <td class="border">H</td>
   <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>D</td>
   <td>E</td>
   <td class="border">H</td>
   <td>F</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="myRow">
   <td class="data">G</td>
   <td class="data">H</td>
   <td class="border">H</td>
   <td class="data">I</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I am extracting the cols `data` in the row `myRow`.

Currently have the xpath of this..

`//table//tr[@class="myRow"]/td[@class="data"]`

This correctly returns me an array of the following nodes.

`<td class="data">G</td>`

`<td class="data">H</td>`

`<td class="data">I</td>`

Returned to me an array, I need to also return what index they are in relation to their parent `<tr>` so that I can use this and get the corresponding header.

Much help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to one of the `td`s (assuming you are using scrapy based on the tags), you can use the XPath `..` to get to its parent:

```
td.xpath('..')
```

Alternatively, you could first select the `th`(es) that you want, and then select the `td`s from there. This would allow you to easily work with each distinct `th` and its children rather than having to filter out duplicates, etc.:

```
for th in response.xpath('//table//tr[@class="myRow"]'):
    # do something with th
    for td in th.xpath('td[@class = "data"]'):
        # do something with td
```